# CSS: working with absolute element inside a relative container

Tags: css

I have a FF problem when using an "absolute" element inside a "relative" container

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="position:relative; height:40px; width:80px">
      <img style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px" src="pic.jpg" />TITLE
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to position the image on the top-left corner of the cell. Therefore I set the img tag to "position:absolute", and the td tag to "position:relative". This is working fine in IE, but not in FF and Chrome. The image appears on the top-left corner of my document. It seems that the "relative" property of the cell container is being ignored.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with these styles?

Comment: just an update. i got it to work (i think) by putting the content of my <td> inside a <div>, then the position:relative property goes to the div.

Comment: If you solved it post you answer! :)

Comment: yeah, i was gonna do that :-). however, I'm not sure if this is the exact solution. please feel free to correct me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it solved by using a div inside the td element.

so the new structure would be:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="position:relative; height:40px; width:80px">
        <img style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px" src="pic.jpg" />TITLE
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The td can't use display:relative (see de [w3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display)). Therefore, you can add a div with width:100% and height:100% that has relative positioning. Then everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem before too. Never found a way other than to wrap the `td` content that I wanted to `position: absolute` in an element (`div`) that had `position: relative`.

Unfortunately it isn't much of an answer. I'd be curious to know the exact reason for this, but my guess is it's due to the *special* display type of table elements.

Comment: i think it is because div has a display:block and the td doesn't. if you give the td a display block, the position:relative must be respected thereafter.. :)